# where are the 21.co bitcoin tutorials?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I had a bunch of links for the 21.co bitcoin tutorials. It was quite extensive, and I thought I would start working on them for some day. The day has come, but I can't find the material.

They have rebranded the website so it became earn.com and I can't find the tutos anywhere on the web. I guess another good reason to dislike coinbase.

If you have info, or a mirror link, or whatever, I would be grateful.

Edit: The url https://earn.com/learn/ gives a 404 which is a sad thing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they have been archived over at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606062213/https:/21.co/learn/).

Comment: Thanks. It's already something, even though some pages redirect to a **404** earn.com page like this one: https://web.archive.org/web/20171031225351/https:/earn.com/learn/diy-bitcoin-computer-odroid-xu4/

Found some links though, I will try to keep them in one place.

- Example link1: https://github.com/ChristopherA/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line